# Create WPF richtextbox dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, richtextbox

I have an application which has a basic text editor features. I use System.Windows.Controls richtextbox for the purpose of opening files. Currently my application can only open one file at a time. However I want to enhance the applicatin to open multpile files in multiple tabs. How do I implement multiple tab feature? I am pretty new to WPF framework.Any help is appreciated. The code I have is as below:

```
<Window x:Class="Editor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  Title="Pattern Editor" Height="400" Width="600"
    >
    <Grid>

        <!-- Set the styles for the tool bar. -->
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="formatTextStyle">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Palatino Linotype"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value ="14"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=mainRTB}"></Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="formatImageStyle">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=mainRTB}"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DockPanel Name="mainPanel" >
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="_File">
                    <MenuItem Header="_New" Click="New_Click"/>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Open" Click="Open_Click"/>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Save" Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" ToolTip="Save" Click="Save_Click">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Editor\Editor\Images\FileSave.png" Height="21"></Image>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Save As" Click="Save_As_Click">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Editor\Editor\Images\FileSaveAs.png" Height="21"></Image>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Close" Click="Close_Click"/>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Click="Exit_Click"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
                    <MenuItem Header="_Cut" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" ToolTip="Cut">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Editor\Editor\Images\EditCut.png" Height="21"></Image>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Copy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" ToolTip="Copy">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="C:\Users\stambi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PatternEditor\PatternEditor\Images\EditCopy.png" Height="21"></Image>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Paste" Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" ToolTip="Paste">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Editor\Editor\Images\EditPaste.png" Height="21"></Image>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Undo" Command="ApplicationCommands.Undo" ToolTip="Undo">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="C:\Users\stambi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PatternEditor\PatternEditor\Images\EditUndo.png" Height="21"></Image>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Redo" Command="ApplicationCommands.Redo" ToolTip="Redo">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Editor\Editor\Images\EditRedo.png" Height="21"></Image>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Tools">
                    <MenuItem Header="_DisplayFormat">
                        <MenuItem Header="_Binary" IsCheckable="True"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="_Hexadecimal" IsCheckable="True"/>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Split" IsCheckable="True" Click="Split_Click"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="_HighLight"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Show Linenumbers"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>

            <!--By default pressing tab moves focus to the next control. Setting AcceptsTab to true allows the 
           RichTextBox to accept tab characters. -->
            <RichTextBox Name="mainRTB" AcceptsTab="True" FontFamily="Arial" FontStretch="Normal" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></RichTextBox>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id start with Creating a TabControl in WPF, 
`<TabControl Height="500" Width="Auto" FontSize="14" Name="Mytabcontrol"> </TabControl>`

Then in your c# code add something like:

```
private void AddTabitem()
{
    TabItem ti = new TabItem();
    ti.Header = "Tab";
    ti.Content = // Your richtextbox;
    Mytabcontrol.Items.Insert(Mytabcontrol.Items.Count, ti);
    Mytabcontrol.SelectedIndex = Mytabcontrol.Items.Count - 1;
```

And then a SelectionChanged Event

```
    Mytabcontrol.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(TabSelectionChanged);
}
```

This code might also get in handy:

```
void TabSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mytabcontrol.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        TabItem ti= Mytabcontrol.SelectedItem as TabItem; // Selected Tab
        if (tabitem.Content != null)
        {
            RichTextBox txt = ti.Content as RichTextBox; // your textbox
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoJo: This works, I am able to open files in different tabs, however I am unable to edit the file.

Comment: @user2495173 are you talking to me? you posted it at the wrong answer i think ;)

Comment: @JoJo: No I tried your approach and most of it works except that, I dont get Automaticscrollbar for the textbox, and I am unable to edit anything in the textbox.

Comment: ow yeah :) i forgot the automatic scrollbar. i will edit that part. but how do you mean you can't edit anything in the textbox? @user2495173

Comment: I did get the scrollBar by: <ScrollViewer  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"><TabControl Width="594" Name="Mytabcontrol" /></ScrollViewer>, I can only read the file, but I cannot edit anything in the textbox.

Comment: I did get it working the problem was with ti.Content = mcRTB rather than ti.Content = range.text. :) However I dont know how to get a Closable tab, any Idea?

Comment: You can create a closable tab by Creating a CustomTabItem that inherit from a TabItem. Add xaml code just like the original tabitem and add a button in it aswell. You can do this by adding a Stackpanel Before the ContentPresenter, and put the ContentPresenter inside the StackPaneland after that code piece add a button. Then in your new CustomTabItem class add a new Eventhandler for this button.

Answer (score 0):

you will need a TabControl

1) add a tabControl to your window

2) add this code in your window source code file

```
        //code for adding tabItems to your tabControl            

        //when you open a file, string[] richtextBoxLines are the lines
        public TabItem TItem(string HeaderText, string[] richtextBoxLines)
        {
            TabItem t = new TabItem();
            t.Header = HeaderText;
            RichTextBox r = new RichTextBox();

            foreach(string s in richtextBoxLines)
            {
                r.Selection.Text += s;
            }

            t.Content = r;
            return t;
        }
        //when you just add a tab
        public TabItem TItem(string HeaderText)
        {
            TabItem t = new TabItem();
            t.Header = HeaderText;
            RichTextBox r = new RichTextBox();
            t.Content = r;
            return t;
        }
```

now, you can just add tabs like in the examples below

```
//read text file text to get an array
string[] allLines = null; //set to value of textfile lines

//you can add a tab with this text
myTabControl.Items.Add(TItem("FileName", allLines));

//or you could also add a tab by creating a new text file
myTabControl.Items.Add(TItem("new Textfile"));
```